# Excel.Application.Workbooks.Open method doesn't exist for Excel x64

Tags: powershell, excel-interop

I have a powershell script that manipulates an excel sheet that I run monthly. I went to run it at the beginning of this month with no modifications and I received the error:

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:1 char:1
+ $Excel.Workbooks.Open("C:\spreadsheet.xlsx")
```

Between then and now, I have upgraded Office to x64
I have confirmed the InterOp still works with Officex32

`$Excel` returns a bunch of methods and properties including Workbooks so InterOp is working.
however `$Excel.Workbooks` returns nothing.

$Excel shows a version 16

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.workbooks?view=excel-pia talks about the Workbooks interface but no mention of it not being functional with the x64 version of Office.

Is this a known issue, am I doing something wrong, and/or is there a workaround other than installing Excelx32.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm using Excel 16 x64 on my machine and `$Excel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Temp\test.xlsx")` is working okay for me, so it doesn't look to be a known issue. Running `$Excel.Workbooks` on its own also returns nothing for me, but I believe that's because Excel interop is returning a pure ComObject rather than a class object (like `$Excel` is of type `ApplicationClass`), however running `$Excel.Workbooks.Count` does show 0 on a new $Excel instance.

Comment: Thanks @NiMux for checking for me. I ended up being able to resolve by reinstalling the Office Suite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by uninstalling and reinstalling Office 365 x64 on my machine.